# MySQL ORDER BY question

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can I add an order by `users_friends.date_created` that governs both select queries.

Here is my MySQL code.

```
(SELECT A.user_id, A.friend_id, B.username, B.avatar
FROM  users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON A.friend_id = B.user_id 
AND A.user_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
UNION
(SELECT A.friend_id, A.user_id, B.username, B.avatar
FROM users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON B.user_id = A.user_id 
AND A.friend_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an outer select with an order by and wrap the union as a derived table

```
SELECT user_id, friend_id, username, avatar FROM (
(SELECT A.user_id, A.friend_id, B.username, B.avatar
FROM  users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON A.friend_id = B.user_id 
AND A.user_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
UNION
(SELECT A.friend_id, A.user_id, B.username, B.avatar
FROM users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON B.user_id = A.user_id 
AND A.friend_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
LIMIT 10
) C
ORDER BY avatar
```

Comment: I got it to work on my own but I'll give you credit for helping me thanks since this answer would probably help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If selecting the date_created column is also allowed in the query then we can order the union of the results as -

```
(SELECT A.user_id, A.friend_id, B.username, B.avatar, A.date_created as createdDate
FROM  users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON A.friend_id = B.user_id 
AND A.user_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
UNION
(SELECT A.friend_id, A.user_id, B.username, B.avatar, A.date_created as createdDate
FROM users_friends AS A 
INNER JOIN users AS B 
ON B.user_id = A.user_id 
AND A.friend_id = 3 
AND A.friendship_status = 1)
order by createdDate LIMIT 10
```